# How to remove the first level elements in hierarchy?

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I have a datalist being generated with ASP, but unfortunately the jQuery script that I'm using to scroll through the results requires the layout to be as so:

```
<div class="itemContainer">
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

ASP generates something that looks like this:

```
<div class="itemContainer">
<div class="item"><span></span><br /></div>
<span></span>
<br />
<div class="item"><span></span><br /></div>
<span></span>
<br />
<div class="item"><span></span><br /></div>
<span></span>
<br />
</div>
```

The problem is that the divs also contain span and br elements, so simply looking for those elements and using the .remove() method doesn't work. I need to delete all the span and br elements, but only the ones that are direct ancestors of the 'itemContainer' div.
I hope that is clear, any help would be much appreciated. Alternatively if there is a way to get ASP to generate a datalist with only divs, that would also be helpful.
Thanks!

Comment: Post the jquery script to scroll these. It's likely that you don't need to remove the spans or breaks. DOM operations are expensive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can traverse from `<div class="item">` to the next `<div class="item">`  with something like

```
// move from first div with class "item" to second
$("div.item:first").nextAll("div.item");
```

But if you really need to remove the immediate `<span>` and `<br>` then

```
$("div.itemContainer > span, div.itemContainer > br").remove();
```

or

```
$("div.itemContainer").children("span,br").remove();
```

will remove only immediate `<span>` and `<br>` children of `<div class="itemContainer">`

Comment: Thanks a lot, I knew it would be something simple and I was just overlooking it ;) Last one worked a treat :)

Answer (score 1):

This will work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".itemContainer").find(">span, >br").remove();
});
```

But as my comment above, you likely don't need to remove these elements first.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this, however it achieves the same result as I was getting. It removes ALL the span and br tags. I only want to remove the ones that are immediate ancestors of the 'itemContainer' div, not the ones inside the 'item' divs.

Comment: Edited above to remove only the 1st level spans / brs.

Answer (score -1):

This should work:

```
var e = $("div.itemContainer div.item:first");
e.next().remove(); // remove span
e.next().remove(); // remove br
e.remove(); // remove the div
```

Completely untested, you cat may get boiled while testing this code. Use with caution.

Comment: He wants only the spans and brs removed.